# Progress bar in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a progress bar on my body. When I click on a button a div appear, we can scoll on this div and I would liked to have also a progress bar for this one. I took the Jquery code of the progress bar

**[MY JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uo34ru7d/44/)**

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

function myFunction() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.height = scrolled + "%";
}

$('button').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
    $(this).text("Open ↓");
  } else {
    $(this).text("Close ↑");
  }
  $('.blue-container').toggleClass('In');
  $('body').toggleClass('hideOverflow');
  $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-container">
  <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
</div>

<button> Open ↓</button>

<div class='blue-container'>
  <div class='blue'>
    <p>Hello ! Scroll down. I would like to have a progress bar for this div, like the body.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cannot see what you tried to solve your own problem. You have all the code needed to create the progressbar.

Comment: update snippet with CSS from fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You need to create same progress setter function like you've set on window, except this one should use blue container scrollable element for scroll position measurement.

Remember that after your blue box is closed, you don't need setting progress from this box anymore, so you should unbind setter function (`$scroller.off('scroll', progressSetter)`). It will be bound again after next opening of blue box.

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.height = scrolled + "%";
}

$('button').on('click', function() {
    var $container = $('.blue-container'),
        $scroller = $container.find('.blue'),
        $btn = $(this),
        $bar = $('#myBar'),
        progressSetter = function () {
          var height = $scroller[0].scrollHeight - $scroller.outerHeight();
          $bar.css({
            height: $scroller.scrollTop() / height * 100 + '%'
          });
        };

  if ($btn.hasClass("clicked")) {
    $btn.text("Open ↓");
    $scroller.off('scroll', progressSetter)
  } else {
    $btn.text("Close ↑");
    $scroller.on('scroll', progressSetter)
  }

  $container.toggleClass('In');
  $('body').toggleClass('hideOverflow');
  $btn.toggleClass("clicked");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uo34ru7d/76/

As I can see, you used example code from tutorial. Try to figure out how this scrolling bound functions work (and event binding itself) and you will be able to create one function for both window and your blue container, make that your homework ;)